# Flutter) How can I control the focal length of frontal camera?

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-camera

Looking at the metadata of selfie, there is a focal length data that tells how widely the selfie has taken.
For example, in my case ( iPhone 15 Pro), I can take my selfie by focal length of 30mm or 23mm, where 23mm picture has wide-range view.

My question is this : Can I control the focal length of the frontal camera by code?

If there is any module available at flutter, please tell me and Thank you very much.